# NSJSONSerialization Causing Crash in Swift when Verifying App Receipt

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to verify my app receipt and have successfully done so with some code I found online. However, I am simulating the event that the user is not connected to the internet when attempting to validate the receipt and am getting a crash when doing so. The following do/catch method causes a crash at the `anyObj` line only when my device is not connected to the internet:

func validateRecipt(){
        var response: NSURLResponse?
        var error: NSError?

```
    var receipt: NSData = NSData()

    if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL {
        if let appReceipt = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            print("Receipt Found")
            receipt = appReceipt
        }else {
            print("Receipt not Found")
        }
    }else {
        print("Could not load Receipt")
    }

    //https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let receiptdata:NSString = receipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed)
    //NSLog("%@",receiptdata)
    let payload:NSString = "{\"receipt-data\" : \"\(receiptdata)\"}"
    let payloadData = payload.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let err: NSError?

    request.HTTPBody = payloadData

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            var err: NSError?

            //let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
            var json: AnyObject?
            do {
                let anyObj = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
            ****//App Crashes Here ^^//****
                json = anyObj

            } catch  {
                print("Fetch failed: \((error as NSError).localizedDescription)")

            }

            if(err != nil) {
                print(err!.localizedDescription)
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
            }
            else {
                if let parseJSON = json {
                    print("Recipt \(parseJSON)")
                    print(parseJSON.count)
                }
                else {
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print("Recipt Error: \(jsonStr)")
                }
    print("You gets nathan")
            }

    })

    task.resume()

}
```

The crash is just `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`

I am having trouble understanding the do/catch method so I am not confident that I fully comprehend what is going on here. So I'm guessing my question is how can I avoid this crashing when anyObj returns nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing the line which the debugger cursor is pointing at is:

```
let anyObj = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

...and your `data` variable is nil (i.e., optional contains no value). Check that before force-unwrapping (`!` operator).

(The `(error as NSError).localizedDescription` can't be, because error is supposed to be non-nil inside the `catch` block and failing to case to `NSError` would give a different error message, I think).

---

#### Edit:

This is how you unwrap safely:

```
if let safeData = data { // <-- YOU NEED TO DO THIS
    // data is 'NSData?', safeData is 'NSData'. 
    
    // If data contained any value, it is now assigned to safeData.
    // Use safeData as the source of your JSON (**not** data).
}
else{
    print("error: data is nil!")
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but this sounds plausible. I added the bit of code where `data` is first mentioned. How can I tell if it is nil?

Comment: It's all in the (very readable) manual by Apple. It is really worth reading: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: I have gone over the documentation but I still cannot see why this is not working.

Comment: You are **still** force-unwrapping `data` (as `data!`). Use the `if/let` construct  and only use the non-nil, non-optional (unwrapped) value.

Comment: I can see what is going on now! For some reason I was thinking that my `NSJSONSerialization` initialization was incorrect and it didn't click in my head that I had to simply test it instead. Thanks alot!

Comment: Yes. The JSON method `throws` an error (i.e., Swift 2 error handling) , which is not the same as a runtime error of the kind you get when unwrapping nil (more like an exception, e.g. dividing by zero).